# How to intersect merge two array by array value

Tags: php

I have to array, in text field might get duplicated data, I want to combine two array into one with unique text

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'a',
    ),
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'b',
    ),
);
$b = array(
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'a',
    ),
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'c',
    ),
);
```

**expected result**

```
array(
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'a',
    ),
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'c',
    ),
    array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => 'b',
    ),
);
```

This is how I do it now

```
$merged = array_merge($a, $b);
$extractText = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['text'];
}, $merged);
$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return array(
        'domain' => 'default',
        'text' => $item
    );
}, array_unique($extractText));
var_dump($result);
```

Looking for origin PHP way or another way more efficient to achieve this.

Comment: Please put your desired result. Not sure what "unique text" means.

Comment: @mitkosoft it's done, thanks

Comment: Seems like you want a array with unique sub arrays, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work -

```
$merged =array_merge($a, $b);
array_unique($merged, SORT_REGULAR);
```

**Output**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "domain" => "default"
    "text" => "a"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "domain" => "default"
    "text" => "b"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "domain" => "default"
    "text" => "c"
  ]
]
```

[array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) for this job, the trick is that you have to specify `SORT_REGULAR` as the second parameter. This prevents `array_unique` from trying to cast the array values as strings:

```
$result = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b), SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [domain] => default
        [text] => a
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [domain] => default
        [text] => b
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [domain] => default
        [text] => c
    )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mmda1)